# Resize in FFmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, bitrate, aspect-ratio, resizing

I have a video which has a resolution of 1920x1080p. I want to re-encode this video (with libx264 for video and aac for audio); Downscale it first to 
1280x720p (with the same aspect ratio) while using a different video bitrate (1900 kbps) and audio bitrate (96 kbps). Also I want to change from 
mkv to mp4. I don't want to change anything of the previous encoding settings (Just the bitrate, and the video size). I want to use variable bitrate 
(in video and audio), but I don't know how to put it in FFmpeg (I have the latest version 3.0- Windows 7). To get better quality, is it of any use to put 
a CRF value along with the variable bitrate (and if yes, how can I do that)? Also if I want to downscale it to 480p how can I do that and keep the 
aspect ratio intact?

One more thing; What is "maxrate", "minrate" and "bufsize" and where can I use these? I think I have seen that CRF uses VBR, but in one article the above were used (for VBR), so I can't tell exactly what to use to get a smaller file size by just decreasing the bitrate (and the video size, if possible).

Also I don't know if VBR mode is proper for the goal I want to achieve, but I have read it's the best mode.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Why are you wanting to re-encode in the first place?

Comment: I want to get a smaller file size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have asked many questions here, but I think you're overthinking it.

Just use `-crf` and `-preset`. Use the highest `-crf` value that still provides an acceptable output and the slowest `-preset` you have patience for. See [FFmpeg Wiki: H.264 Video Encoding Guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264) for more info.

As for scaling, just use the [scale filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#scale) like this: `-vf scale=1280:-2` or `-vf scale=480:-2`. The `-2` will tell the filter to preserve aspect **and** slightly adjust the output if necessary to make it divisible by 2 which is required by x264 for output with YUV 4:2:0 chroma subsampling.

Comment: Thank you very much. Are these the same; `-preset:v slow` and `-preset slow`? And for the audio? Which of these should I use; `-vbr` or `-b:a`?

Comment: @KLNy `-preset` and `-preset:v` are basically the same. One just has a stream specifier to ensure that `ffmpeg` knows to apply the option to video and not audio, etc (although I don't think there are any audio encoders that use `-preset`); if in doubt use `-preset:v`. If you're using libfdk_aac audio encoder, use `-vbr`, otherwise use `-b:a`. See [FFmpeg Wiki: AAC](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/AAC).

Comment: I read also about `-q:a` for variable in aac; Can I use this (the values?)?

Comment: @KLNy Yes. See [FFmpeg Wiki: AAC](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/AAC) for more info.